# How do I use the value of a cell in a userform label?

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching and found various links, but none seem to address the problem that I have.

I have a userform with a label, and I want the caption of the label to be whatever cell B2 is. This is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
    UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
End Sub
```

My problem is that I have a `Label1_Click()` and the label only appears in my userform when I click. Which do I choose to make the label appear in my userform immediately as it opens?

Comment: If you want the value to appear when the form is launched, use the form initialise method. If you want it to happen after a trigger, define what your trigger is

Answer (score 1):

Either:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Label1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Or:

Change settings of the label if you don't want it hidden at all:

- Click label in editor
- Under properties change `Visible` to `True`

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work. Visibility under properties is set to True, and I have the following codes: https://i.imgur.com/kjHOUw7.jpg

Comment: Maybe some overlapping label? It should be fine, but test this using `Me.Label1.ZOrder msoSendToFront` within the userform initialize. Maybe also good to have a small printscreen from your userform where your label is positioned.

Comment: Do you have a frame in your form? maybe it's hiding behind that?

Comment: @JvdV I've tried with a brand new excel file and it's still not working properly. When I click on the label in the userform, the label then changes to the cell value, but when the userform is first initialized, it does not take the cell value. Are you sure that `Private Sub Label1_Click()` is correct?

Comment: @Zac No frames in my userform. I suspect it might be `Private Sub Label1_Click()` that is wrong, but I have no idea what else to use instead of that.

Comment: @Woels, Pls send/upload your brand new Excel file.

Comment: @JvdV I removed the `Private Sub Label1_Click()` and inserted `UserForm1.Label1.Caption = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value`into the userform instead, and that seems to have fixed it: https://i.imgur.com/GV93vTE.jpg